# MySQL/Spring: Cannot delete or update a parent row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read a few of the posts asking the same question really, but I can't seem to figure out if I'm thinking about my code wrong. 
I am trying to follow a tutorial on Udemy for Java Spring but I try to build something on the side and add extra functionality myself to get a better idea of what I'm learning. I setup the small db below with the 2 tables.

The `users` table is a table that contains user information on a basic blog system. The `posts` table contains a list of blog posts that are associated with users.

If I understand correctly, this would generate a one to many relationship, with each user having several posts. In order to tie a post to a user, I setup the foreign key with the field `author` in the `posts` table referencing the `id` field in the `user` table. I also want to have the ability to delete a user but still leave all their posts there. How can I achieve this?

Right now my application works the other way around, namely it deletes a post just fine and the user is not affected. How could I do this the other way around?

Am I correct in the way I organised the tables themselves? Also, I don't necessarily want to use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 as I'm aware of that one. If foreign_key_checks are disabled, it could lead to further issues down the line right? Of course, assuming my application is limited only to these 2 tables, I should be able to just set the checks to 0 for the purpose of playing around with it, however, if I was to extend it down the line or add additional functionality, this could cause problems (right?) :D

PS - I'm not adding the Java code since it isn't relevant right now seeing that this is just a db error that gets thrown my way :(

```
drop table if exists `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int not null auto_increment,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` char(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY usr_id (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1 auto_increment=1 DEFAULT;

drop table if EXISTS `posts`;

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title` varchar(255),
    `author` int,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `excerpt` text NOT NULL,
    `featured_media` blob,
    `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY post_id (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (author)
        REFERENCES users(id) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1 auto_increment=1;


insert into users VALUE (
    '1','username','UserAuthor','AuthorFirstName','AuthorLastName','author@authoremail.com','test12345');

insert into posts (title,author,date,excerpt,featured_media,content,category) VALUE (
    'First Post',
    '1',
    '2019-1-18 05:30:50',
    'This is just an excerpt of the full text below',
    NULL,
    'This is just an excerpt of the full text below. This is below. This is the full text. Fancy, isn't it?',
    'shitpost'
);
```

EDIT: Later edit - I'm more interested to see how this is really done by companies like reddit for example. You can still have the comments of users who have since deleted their accounts. So in that sense, how is that achieved there? I'm sure foreign keys must be used to link the tables that would hold information tying in users with their comments/posts. I've also seen that another option might be to have another column that would show if the user is active or non active. But then from this the problem changes into - how would this work in the context of a java application? If a delete is sent through, the flag is changed to 'Y' ...?

Comment: FYI: your question title doesn't suits on your real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to retain posts without any information whatsoever about the author (e.g. that several posts were written by the same ex-user), try:

```
    FOREIGN KEY (author)
        REFERENCES users(id) 
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

as per [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Personally, I'd be inclined to keep the user records, anonymise them and mark them as inactive.

> how would this work in the context of a java application?

Well, your delete method would issue an `UPDATE` SQL command instead of a `DELETE`.

Comment: This seems to be very close to what I was thinking about... For my purposes the on delete set null seems to be the most relevant as I might not want to keep any of those details. However, the other solution suggested by bilal of just adding another column could also work.

Answer (score 0):

> how this is really done by companies like reddit for example. You can
>   still have the comments of users who have since deleted their
>   accounts.

Your question is having answer

> I've also seen that another option might be to have another column
>   that would show if the user is active or non active

They all are doing same thing, they aren't deleting user-info but they set user as  with some field like **is_deleted=true**

Maintaining a history table is also a way to store data of any user whether they are in system or not. But you can see after deleted user account the post has the user's name. So definitley it is the flagged column that is telling.

> how would this work in the context of a java application? If a delete is sent through

Yes when you get a delete request you can update your database with is_deleted = True